# btrfs snapshots without subvolumes?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, btrfs, snapshot

I'm starting to use btrfs.  I want to be able to snapshot certain directories but do not want to create sub-volumes.  Is this possible?

Comment: I dont think so. Why don't you want subvolumes? Subvolumes are one of those things that makes btrft great.

Comment: Going to read up on subvolumes more today.

Comment: Also, snapshots _are_ subvolumes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Do `cp --reflink=auto /src/dir /dest/dir`. For all practical purposes it behaves like read & write snapshot of the given directory.

(If you use this command across independent btrfs partitions or outside the btrfs it will perform an ordinary copy)